# How to prevent wasi-sdk clang++ from inserting __wasm_call_ctors call to every exported function?

Tags: webassembly, clang++

I'm building C++ WASM application using wasi-sdk (versions 17 and 20 tested) clang++ as a compiler. I'm running the WASM code using WAMR in a custom embedded runtime. I use WAMR build-in libc instead of wasi-sdk's one. The application does not have `main()` - it exports few functions that the runtime calls when necessary. The problem I have is that clang++ inserts calls to constructors of static objects to all of my entry points.

Sample code:

```cpp
struct Bar
{
    Bar() {}
};

Bar bar;

extern "C" void foo() {}
```

The build command I use is:

```
/opt/wasi-sdk/bin/clang++ -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--allow-undefined -Wl,--export=foo -nostdlib -lc++ -lc++abi test.cpp
```

This results WASM code that calls c'tors every time (showing only foo export):

```
  (func $foo (type 0)
    return)
  (func $foo.command_export (type 0)
    call $__wasm_call_ctors         <<< this is the problem
    call $foo)
  (export "foo" (func $foo.command_export)))
```

-nostdlib -lc++ -lc++abi are needed to get rid of wasi-sdk libc, but still provide it's C++ standard library. If I compile without these flags the export is as expected:

```
  (export "foo" (func $foo)))
```

**Question: how to prevent clang++ from inserting calls to static object c'tors?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `-Wl,--no-entry` removed `_start` function that normally calls `__wasm_call_ctors`. As static c'tors were now not called, clang decided to insert those wrappers to each and every exported function to ensure statics constructors are called. Apparently this is a feature - here's a good discussion about this: https://reviews.llvm.org/D62922.

So the solution is to

- use linker flags `-mexec-model=reactor -nostdlib -lc++ -lc++abi`
- provide wasm function `_initialize` that just calls `__wasm_call_ctors`
- call `_initialize` from the runtime as a 1st thing once the WASM module
  is loaded